# How to have mp3 files in some sort of database and access in ios?

Tags: iphone, sql, ios, audio, mp3

I'm new to iOS, and I'm trying to write an app that uses mp3 files. In fact, this app will have a lot of mp3 files, and in order to avoid a huge app that takes a ton of space and forever to download, I wanted to put it into some sort of database or file server, and when the user clicks on the name of song, the app accesses the database and loads the file. How do I do this? Is it with an SQLite database?

Thanks,
Gagan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make sure you become intimately familiar with [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html), Apple's persistence framework.  I'd stay away from doing raw SQLite access, just because CoreData will do all of the heavy lifting for you.  Just as a pointer, I wouldn't store the MP3 files themselves in CoreData, but rather store the file system references to them.

If the Apple documentation is a little dry for you, [Pro Core Data](http://www.apress.com/9781430233558) from Apress is an excellent primer for learning the basics of CoreData, as well as progressively going deeper into the intricacies of the framework.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! I'll look at the documentation for it. And I often do find the documentation to be a bit dry, so the Apress will be my first resource. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create NSData and insert that into the the model. There is a another post with a snippet of code that could be useful to you here: [Download, save, and play mp3 on an iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377787/download-save-and-play-mp3-on-an-iphone)

CoreData can be intimidating if you have not experienced it yet, but in reality it is a very easy to use. If you are not familiar with CoreData I would suggest checking out the Docs from Apple and spend a few hours googling and crating "test" apps to learn how to create, insert and delete managed objects. Here is Apples Docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect an answer that fast! Thank you! I will check out the documentation. Definitely will create a few test apps first.

Comment: It is not advisable to convert the files to data and then store it... rather just store the file in documents directory and store the paths in persistence storage..